# Why does a increase in value but not trigger the following if function?

Tags: mql4, forex, mql

So I am trying to identify a certain pattern by splitting it into 2 parts a and b. the ea is able to find the a but fails to proceed and run b.

```
    double EMA77 = iMA(NULL,5,77,0,1,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
    double EMA9 = iMA(NULL,5,9,0,1,PRICE_CLOSE,1);
    double NEMA77 = NormalizeDouble(EMA77,5);
    double NEMA9 = NormalizeDouble(EMA9,5);


    if(NEMA9 > NEMA77){
      a = a+1;
      Alert(a + " a value");
      }

    if(a>0 && NEMA77==NEMA9){
      b = b+1;
      Alert(b + "b value");
      }
```

Comment: I dont know what the first 4 lines do. But within the first if you ask for NEMA9 to be greater than NEMA77. That's apprently true and a is increased. So the second if will not be true, because NEMA77 is not equal to NEMA9. NEMA9 is greater than NEMA77

Comment: I can see what you are trying to achieve, however it is statistically highly unlikely that a 77 SMA would ever exactly equal a 9 SMA at the close of a bar. EMA crosses would usually occur between bars. If you can explain the pattern you are trying to detect you will probably receive further assistance.

Comment: @PaulB So what I am trying to achieve is a buy signal when 2 ema's touch and then resume to go in the same direction. So in this case the EMA9 is greater, then it declines and touches the EMA77 and then again increases(the code for the last part I did not post). So I am looking for a pullback that is based on 2 ema's. I figured that 2 ema's are never equal therefore I tried rounding them up but it seemed to have not made any changes or I haven't done it properly.

Comment: As it is unlikely that 2 MA's would just "touch", you would need to define some sort of buffer or tolerance, and if the 2 MA's achieve this you can then trach what they do